# Haskell ghci Variable not in scope

Tags: haskell, sublimetext3, ghci

Hello im using sublime text 3 and my cmd shell with ghci.
I wrote following function in st3:

```
testing :: Int -> Bool
testing 0 = True
testing 1 = False
testing n = testing(n mod 2)
```

I know haskell provides an even function but we have to write our own even function so i came up with this. When im loading the file into the ghci:

```
:cd <pathtofile>
:l myfile.hs
```

and try to execute my function with

```
testing 10
```

i get this error:

```
 Variable not in scope: testing :: t0 -> t
```

I should probably mention that testing :: Int -> Bool shares the file with a fibonacci function but 
that shouldnt be the problem right? 
Any help appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you execute the `:l myfile.hs` command?

Comment: It says 'Ok, one module loaded'

Comment: i tried restarting everything, found out that i need to use `mod` instead of mod. Works perfectly fine now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n mod 2` is wrong syntax, you have two possibilities here:

- `mod n 2`
- `` n `mod` 2 ``

Comment: yeah after some restarting and reloading, also changed the mod, everything works now thank you!

Comment: n \`mod\` 2 is exactly the same as `mod n 2` though

Comment: @larek Yep, I was giving the two possiblities. But will re-estate it.

Comment: @ElBaulP good stuff. I was commenting on the original version of this answer, my comment makes way less sense with how the answer is now :)

Comment: @larek, no worries, Thanks, I improved the answer just because of your comment, so it was useful ;-)